# hollow square plate mesh

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I have this square region and I want to generate a mesh it using quadrilateral elements for it and get the coordinates and incidents

[image: plate]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Mesh+F1 can get you quite far. Notice that your question could be migrated to any related site and no one would know it had anything to do with Mathematica.

Answer (score 8):

Here is something to get you started:

```
r1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {30, 30}];
r2 = Rectangle[{10, 10}, {20, 20}];

reg = DiscretizeRegion@RegionDifference[r1, r2]
MeshCoordinates @ reg
```

[image: region]

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-15, -15}, {15, 15}], 
   Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}]], "MeshOrder" -> 1]
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

```
mesh["Coordinates"]
{{5., -5.}, {5., -3.33333},...}

ElementIncidents[mesh["MeshElements"]]
{{{265, 303, 87}, {25, 57, 176}, ....
```

**Update:**

If you want quad elements you can get those with the [FEMAddOns Paclet](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns).

Install the current paclet with:

```
ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][]
```

The load the paclet:

```
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
```

Convert the triangle mesh to a quad mesh:

```
quadMesh = ToQuadMesh[mesh]
quadMesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you that is great but I want to use quadrilateral element instead or triangular one

Comment: @AmrSaleh, see update for quad element mesh.

Answer (score 3):

```
DiscretizeRegion[LaminaData["FilledSquareWithSquareHole", "Region"][30, 10]]
```

[image]

Use the option `MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> None, 1->Black}` in `DiscretizeRegion` to get

[image]

```
LaminaData["FilledSquareWithSquareHole", "Diagram"]
```

[image]

Comment: may I ask a question, how can we install FEMAddOns in windows? I give a try, however, i have no idea how to install FEMAddOns.paclet, I never find such FEMAddOns.paclet folder...

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, you can find installation instructions in the link given in user21's answer: [GitHub FEMAAddOns package](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns)

Comment: thanks! but the form of a .paclet file???

Comment: okay, I find paclet file! thanks!